# Close an opened file which was opened with another program in linux

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, file, watchdog

I have a software which uses watchdog just after boot, as long as the main program makes watchdog busy, I dont have any access to /dev/watchdog file. I need to get the access of this file by force and close it so that i can open it from another application again.
My main program has only 1 running instance at a time.

I have tried some tricks for example sending V char to /dev/watchdog,
using WDIOS_DISABLECARD to disable watchdog,
kill the other process,
But they are not something I am looking for.

I have only one running process so closing an open file by other process means that the main process has been crashed without closing the watchdog properly and is no longer alive.

Comment: It's not generally possible to close files in another process. If you could close a file that another program is using, it will almost certainly cause the program to malfunction, so you might as well just kill it.

Comment: I don't think that is possible. Imagine that you had a syscall `close2(pid, fd)` that closes the file of another process. But that process still belives that `fd` is opened and uses it for read/write (that would trigger a EBADF). Then, that process opens another random file that happens to reuse the same numeric file descriptor. Now it won't get EBADF anymore but the wrong data from the wrong file!

Comment: In my case, there is no other process. I mean if the main process was running I can not run another one. but sometimes the main process crashes without closing the watchdog file descriptor. so I can not run another instance of process because watchdog is busy and I have to wait until system's reboot.
I dont want that and I want o replace the process and open the watchdog immedetly

Answer (score 0):

It is within the definition of a process that a process owns all of the file handles that it has opened, and that the file handles are only meaningful within that process. So, even if you could somehow communicate a file handle from one process to another, this file handle will be meaningless in the other process, or it might refer to a completely unrelated file in the other process. Thus, it is generally impossible to close a file that some other process has opened.

Luckily, it is also within the definition of a process that when the process terminates, all file handles owned by that process are automatically closed by the operating system.

So, what you want to do is to kill the process that keeps the file open. And that is okay, because if you could somehow close that file then that process would crash anyway next time it attempts to use that file.